# Angular 4 animate parent and child components at the same time

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I've written plunk to illustrate my issue: [LINK](https://plnkr.co/edit/Wm5x2zLg9HsGdtk8tAEz?p=preview)

I need to animate parent component, and at the same time I want to make some animation in child component. It seems that angular is blocking animation on child component, and then simply jumps states after parent animation ends without any transition.

Is there any way to make animations work in parallel, or at least chain without using callbacks?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'outer',
  template: `
    <div [@state]="state" (mouseenter)="state='wide'" (mouseleave)="state='narrow'" style="background-color: red;">
      <inner [stateInner]="state"></inner>
    </div>`,
  animations:[
    trigger('state', [
      state('narrow', style({
        width: '100px'
      })),
      state('wide', style({
        width: '400px'
      })),
      transition('* => *', animate('500ms'))
    ])  
  ]
})
export class Outer {
  public state: string = 'narrow';
  constructor() {
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'inner',
  template: `
    <div [@stateInner]="stateInner">
      <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>`,
  animations:[
    trigger('stateInner', [
      state('narrow', style({
        height: '100px'
      })),
      state('wide', style({
        height: '400px'
      })),
      transition('* => *', animate('500ms'))
    ])  
  ]
})
export class Inner {
  @Input() stateInner: string = 'narrow';
  constructor() {
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd like to say that using callbacks is *the* best way to handle this for future code, but if you just need to get this to work the trick is to use `OnChanges`, `SimpleChanges`, and a setTimeout().

[Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/P98nMtiQTL42njYZyW97?p=preview) to show how it works, as well as the inner div main changes in code:

*imports*

```
import {Component, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core'
```

*template*

```
  template: `
    <div [@stateInner]="localChange">
      <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
```

*class export*

```
  localChange = 'narrow';

  ngOnChanges( changes: SimpleChanges ) {
    console.log(changes)
    setTimeout( () => this.localChange = changes.stateInner.currentValue, 500);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run parent and child animations at the same time without events and timeouts, [animateChild()](https://angular.io/guide/animations#parallel-animation-groups) can help us. Here is the parent animations description:

```
animations: [
    trigger('state', [
        state('narrow', style({
            width: '100px'
        })),
        state('wide', style({
            width: '400px'
        })),
        transition('narrow => wide', [
            style({
                width: '100px'
            }),
            group([
                animate('500ms', style({
                    width: '400px'
                })),
                query('@stateInner', [
                    animateChild()
                ])
            ])
        ]),
        transition('wide => narrow', [
            style({
                width: '400px'
            }),
            group([
                animate('500ms', style({
                    width: '100px'
                })),
                query('@stateInner', [
                    animateChild()
                ])
            ])
        ])
    ])
]
```

[group()](https://angular.io/api/animations/group) - runs multiple animations in parallel, here is an example from the documentation

[query()](https://angular.io/api/animations/query) - finds child animations

[animateChild()](https://angular.io/api/animations/animateChild) - executes child animations

The drawback of this solution, as you may notice, I described *forward* and *backward* parent transitions and styles separately, otherwise the parent state isn't animated correctly for some reason. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726044/angular-transition-between-states-isnt-animated-correctly-if-animate-is-place) is my question about the problem.