# Angular5 : Mix animateChild(), transition() and state() with nested divs

Tags: angular, animation, nested, grouping

Using Angular 5, I am trying to achieve something I believe to be really obvious. But I cannot get it working.

Suppose I have two nested divs with an animation on each (with states and transition). I just want to launch the both at the same time when the state changes.

Of course, I tried to use `animateChild()` and `group()` methods, but ... It still don't work. I don't get how to mix `state()`, 'transition()' and `animateChild()`.

If somebody can help.

Here is a really simplified plunker : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-animations-state-and-animatechild?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Here is an working example, very similar to your sample:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51724621/4858777